# Windows: BSOD general troubleshooting tips

Tags: windows, troubleshooting, bsod

I know three methods of troubleshooting BSOD. Are there some advanced tips i'm missing?

1. BSOD is not very informative, but googling the error code provides with some semi-useful info
2. Look thru system log messages
3. Using [Debugging tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) for minidump analyzis.

   [Kernel debugger front-end](http://4u3u.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!D49B37B43E9E7B5E!311.entry) is handy for fetching data like this:

   ```
   Crash date:         Wed Aug 23 15:33:31.707 2006 (GMT+4) 
   Stop error code:    0xA 
   Process name:       OUTLOOK.EXE 
   Probably caused by: SYMEVENT.SYS ( SYMEVENT+b124 )
   ```

Any other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually a quick Google search for the file (in your case SYMEVENT.SYS) followed by "blue screen" or "BSOD" is enough to get you on the right track.

I did a quick Google search for "SYMEVENT.SYS blue screen" and found the following link:

http://www.naterice.com/articles/36

You can also look at the dump files (as mentioned in the article).

Since you didn't mention much info about your system setup or situation its hard to know what direction to point you in.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm just wondering what to do when BSOD comes out, and i'm not having this very error: pasted it here just for instance :)

Comment: Same overall strategy would apply.  Look what what file the error is caused in/by (your example was SYMEVENT.SYS) and then do a google search for:  "YOURFILE.SYS blue screen" (no quotes) or "YOURFILE.SYS BSOD"  Most of the time someone else has had the same problem as you and you'll find clues as to what you might have done or what is going on with your system.